# PHP Pagination issues and errors

Tags: php, pagination

I'm learning PHP at the moment.
I want to make my HTML page pagination.
Here is the code I have:

I'm trying to make 6 videos only per page. And to do that I'm going to search how many ID's I have it means I have that same value of videos so I can make X pages.

At the moment, I'm having this error:

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\Site\index.php on line 20

```
$stmt3 = $db->prepare ("SELECT COUNT(ID_Video) as total FROM Videos");

$stmt3->execute();

$result2 = $stmt3->get_result();
$result2->fetch_assoc();

// Remember to round it up always!
$VideosPerPage = 6;
$totalPages = ceil($result2 / $VideosPerPage);

// Check that the page number is set.
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    $_GET['page'] = 0;
}else{
    // Convert the page number to an integer
    $_GET['page'] = (int)$_GET['page'];
}

// If the page number is less than 1, make it 1.
if($_GET['page'] < 1){
    $_GET['page'] = 1;
    // Check that the page is below the last page
}else if($_GET['page'] > $totalPages){
    $_GET['page'] = $totalPages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this error because `$result2` is PDO result- not an integer. You need to assign the fetched value from the result in a variable. You can use `fetchColumn()` as you are getting one column. Your first few lines could look like following:

```
$result2 = $stmt3->get_result();
$totalVideos = $result2->fetchColumn(); // will get the number from single column

// Remember to round it up always!
$VideosPerPage = 6;
$totalPages = ceil($totalVideos / $VideosPerPage);
```